# Scrapy nested item image pipeline

Tags: python, class, scrapy, pipeline

I have a nested scrapy item.

```
class MyItem(scrapy.Item):
    name= scrapy.Field()
    sub_item_id = scrapy.Field()
    sub_item = scrapy.Field() # Another MyItem()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    image_paths = scrapy.Field()
```

I have written my pipeline so if `MyItem()` has `parent_item` then I recurse and process first `parent_item` and if `parent_item` has own `parent_item` then I recurse again...

When the functions return back, they return an ID value so I know what was done. For example after processing, `item1->item2->item3` could be as:

```
item1['name'] = 'item1'
item1['sub_item_id'] = 10
item1['sub_item'] = item2

item2['name'] = 'item2'
item2['parent_item_id'] = 15
item2['parent_item'] = item3

item3['name'] = 'item3'
item3['parent_item_id'] = None
item3['parent_item'] = None
```

So in my database I have `id, parent_id, name` fields and when I enter the items I am able to enter the correct `parent_id`

This works perfectly for normal item pipelines. But now I am trying to do a similar thing using `ImagesPipeline` But `ImagesPipeline` executes `get_media_requests()` then returns results to `item_completed()`. With other pipelines I am able to call internal methods to go deeper in nested `Item` structure. So the question is how can I operate on nested `Item`s starting from depest one going backwards with `ImagesPipeline`?

As I imagine, I will need to recurse in `get_media_requests()` and send `parent_item` to `ImagesPipeline` again and wait for it to return an item. But I am not sure how to do this exactly. In normal pipeline I simply call the methods recursively but now I need to pass `parent_item` to pipeline class manually and wait for it to return?

If I extract all image URLs from the nested items and parse all in one go, then I would later need to figure out which image was from which item etc. I am not sure if it would be easy. Probably would need to hash all the URLs and compare with file names etc. It may become messy...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I don’t really understand what you want too well, but I suggest you review the code of the built-in images pipeline, learn how it works, and consider writing your own pipeline based on it that works the way you want.

Comment: I updated and tried to make the problem more clear. I already have modified the default ImagesPipeline and I am using custom pipelines.